# How to do Advanced Filtering in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this data

```
Group Id   Name
1          Bob
1          Jim
1          Jane
2          Bill
2          Jack
3          Lisa
```

Now I want to filter each group down to only 2 results. If less than 2 results just return all

Final Result

```
Group Id   Name
1          Bob
1          Jim
2          Bill
2          Jack
3          Lisa
```

Comment: which 2?  First two by current row number?

Comment: the first 2 it finds from each group. As you can see from the final result Jane is no longer in the list.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is sorted by Group ID, then add a column C, with a formula of:

```
=IF(A2=A1,C1+1,1)
```

This just creates a simple running count of identical group id.  Then, filter your list for values <=2.